# Reverse a number and sum of digits in sql

Tags: sql

In sql database i have a table .In which I have column A is decimal(18,0) type.

```
A
34
123
345
879
```

I need column B and C as like this

```
B      C
43     7
321    6 
543    12
978    24
```

Comment: what is your dbms? like Oracle, SQL Server, MySQL etc..also what have you tried so far?

Comment: See answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34081156/sum-of-digits-of-a-number-in-sql-server-without-using-traditional-loops-like-whi the sum of digits will not chage when you reverse the number.

Comment: How many digits can each value have?

Comment: `A.val % 10 + A.val / 10 % 10 + A.val / 100 % 10...`

Comment: A is decimal(18,0) type

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For Postgres you can use `string_to_array()` to split the number into digits:

```
with data (a) as (
  values
    (34),
    (123),
    (345),
    (879)
)
select a, 
       string_agg(t.d::text, '' order by t.idx desc) as b, 
       sum(t.d::int) as c
from data, 
     unnest(string_to_array(a::text,null)) with ordinality as t(d, idx)
group by a;
```

The above returns:

```
a   | b   | c 
----+-----+---
 34 | 43  |  7
123 | 321 |  6
345 | 543 | 12
879 | 978 | 24
```

To get the reversed number, you could also use `reverse()` in Postgres

Answer (score 1):

> In Oracle, it can be done as follows -

```
SELECT 
    VALUE, REVERSE_VALUE, SUM(SUM_TOT) AS SUM 
FROM (
        SELECT 
            DISTINCT A AS VALUE, REVERSE(TO_CHAR(A)) AS REVERSE_VALUE, SUBSTR(TO_CHAR(A), LEVEL, 1) AS SUM_TOT 
        FROM (
                SELECT 34 AS A FROM DUAL
                UNION
                SELECT 123 FROM DUAL
                UNION
                SELECT 345 FROM DUAL
                UNION
                SELECT 879 FROM DUAL
            )
        CONNECT BY LEVEL <= LENGTH(TO_CHAR(A))
        ORDER BY 1
    )
GROUP BY 
    VALUE, REVERSE_VALUE
;
```

> Output -

```
VALUE|REVERSE_VALUE|SUM
34|43|7
345|543|12
123|321|6
879|978|24
```