# sum of factorial of the no

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

Want to find sum of digits of factorial of a num?

But i need the sum of the result like 5! is 120 
in this i want 1+2+0=3

Comment: what have you tried till now? and where are you struck? We are not here to work on your assigment.

Comment: if you have problem with factorial, refer to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3504932/sql-functions-factorial

Comment: and then to sum up individual digits refer to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34081156/sum-of-digits-of-a-number-in-sql-server-without-using-traditional-loops-like-whi

Answer (score 1):

This can be achieved with help of recursive CTE:

```
--here you decide what factorial to calculate
declare @i int = 5;
;with cte as(
    select 1 n, 1 factorial
    union all
    select n + 1, factorial * (n + 1) from cte
    where n < @i
)
select factorial,
       --just to make sure we correctly sum all digits
       (factorial%100000)/10000 + 
       (factorial%10000)/1000 + 
       (factorial%1000)/100 + 
       (factorial%100)/10 + 
       factorial%10 DigitsSum
from cte
where n = @i
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use code like this:

```
declare @a int
set @a = 120
declare @temp varchar(20)
set @temp = cast(@a as varchar(20))
declare @Result int
set @Result = 0
declare @tempLength int
set @tempLength = DATALENGTH(@temp)
while @tempLength > 0
begin
    set @Result = @Result + cast(SUBSTRING(@temp, @tempLength, 1) as int)
    set @tempLength = @tempLength - 1
end
select @Result
```

Variable "a" is same your factorial result.

Answer (score -1):

try substring() function and separate  the digits and then add all togather.

Answer (score -1):

You can Create a function from [sum of factorial of the no](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52160540/sum-of-factorial-of-the-no#52160724) To Find out the Factorial of a number.
 Then use below query to find the Sum:

```
    DECLARE @var1 int   
    select @var1 = dbo.Factorial(5)

    ;WITH i AS (
        SELECT @var1 / 10 n, @var1 % 10 d

        UNION ALL

        SELECT n / 10, n % 10
        FROM i
        WHERE n > 0
    )
    SELECT SUM(d)
    FROM i;
```

Comment: and so this this answer !

Comment: if you are going to copy & paste somebody else answer, please at least include reference also